# Search in a string and obtain the 2 words before and after the match in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm using Python to search some words (also multi-token) in a description (string).

To do that I'm using a regex like this

```
    result = re.search(word, description, re.IGNORECASE)
    if(result):
        print ("Trovato: "+result.group())
```

But what I need is to obtain the first 2 word before and after the match. For example if I have something like this:

> Parking here is horrible, this shop sucks.

"**here is**" is the word that I looking for. So after I matched it with my regex I need the 2 words (if exists) before and after the match.

In the example:
**Parking** here is **horrible, this**

"Parking" and horrible, this are the words that I need.

**ATTTENTION**
The description cab be very long and the pattern "here is" can appear multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this (*edit: added anchors to cover most cases*):

```
(\S+\s+|^)(\S+\s+|)here is(\s+\S+|)(\s+\S+|$)
```

Like this you will always have 4 groups (might have to be trimmed) with the following behavior:

1. If group 1 is empty, there was no word before (group 2 is empty too)
2. If group 2 is empty, there was only one word before (group 1)
3. If group 1 and 2 are not empty, they are the words before in order
4. If group 3 is empty, there was no word after
5. If group 4 is empty, there was only one word after
6. If group 3 and 4 are not empty, they are the words after in order

Corrected [demo link](https://www.regex101.com/r/oW3zG0/6)

Comment: Love your solution... but look at this example https://www.regex101.com/r/oW3zG0/3
the pattern used is "di"... The only match that I need is "5 pollici di tipo crystal"
... So I need the space " di " in the pattern

Comment: @UsiUsi One problem remaining like this, if you have "it was a nice evening. we went to ..." and you look for "evening" it won't find it because of the dot, would need some fine-tuning depending on your data.

Comment: @UsiUsi good enough? You could try the following to consume optional symbols before and after the match, if you need them, add two additional groups: `(\S+\s+|^)(\S+\s+|)([^\sa-zA-Z0-9]*)here is([^\sa-zA-Z0-9]*)(\s+\S+|)(\s+\S+|$)`, so you have group 1,2 before, 3 symbols before, 4 symbols after, 5 and 6 after. https://www.regex101.com/r/oW3zG0/7

Answer (score 1):

How about string operations?

```
line = 'Parking here is horrible, this shop sucks.'

before, term, after = line.partition('here is')
before = before.rsplit(maxsplit=2)[-2:]
after = after.split(maxsplit=2)[:2]
```

Result:

```
>>> before
['Parking']
>>> after
['horrible,', 'this']
```

Comment: I get this error TypeError: rsplit() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: What if Line is a long description and the patterns "here is" can appear multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex: `((?:[a-z,]+\s+){0,2})here is\s+((?:[a-z,]+\s*){0,2})`

with `re.findall` and `re.IGNORECASE` set

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/oW3zG0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, this becomes a bit more complicated.  The solution below deals with scenarios where the searched pattern may in fact also be in the two preceding or two subsequent words.

```
line = "Parking here is horrible, here is great here is mediocre here is here is "
print line
pattern = "here is"
r = re.search(pattern, line, re.IGNORECASE)
output = []
if r:
    while line:
        before, match, line = line.partition(pattern)
        if match:
            if not output:
                before = before.split()[-2:]
            else:    
                before = ' '.join([pattern, before]).split()[-2:]
            after = line.split()[:2]
            output.append((before, after))
print output
```

**Output from my example would be:**

*[(['Parking'], ['horrible,', 'here']), (['is', 'horrible,'], ['great', 'here']), (['is', 'great'], ['mediocre', 'here']), (['is', 'mediocre'], ['here', 'is']), (['here', 'is'], [])]*